# JavaScript Beginner Level - Need help understanding Math.random and "quotes.length"

Tags: javascript, arrays

and I need help understanding some parts of this
Example I am doing out the Sams Teach Yourself HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.

A few things they did not explain in the lesson is this line here
"i = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);"

How does quotes.length and Math.random work?
Also I am having a hard time understanding this block of code..

```
"//Write out the quote as HTML
        document.write("<p style='background-color: #ffb6c1'>\"");
        document.write(quotes[i] + "\"");
        document.write("<em>-" + sources[i] + "</em>");
        document.write("</p>");"
```

Any help will be appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Quotable Quotes</title>

    <script>
      <!-- Hide the script from old browsers
      function getQuote() {
        //Create the Arrays
        var quotes = new Array(4);
        var sources = new Array(4);

        // Initialize the arrays with quotes
        quotes[0] = "When I was a boy of 14, my father was so " +
        "ignorant...but when I got to be 21 I was astonished" +
        "at how much he had learned in 7 years.";
        sources[0] = "Mark Twain";

        quotes[1] = "Everybody is ignorant. Only on different " +
        "subjects.";
        sources [1] = "Will Rogers";

        quotes[2] = "They say such nice things about people at " +
        "their funerals that it makes me sad that I'm going to " +
        "miss mine by just a few days.";
        sources[2] = "Garrison Keillor";

        quotes[3] = "What's another word for thesaurus?";
        sources[3] = "Steven Wright";

        //Get a random index into the arrays
        i = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);

        //Write out the quote as HTML
        document.write("<p style='background-color: #ffb6c1'>\"");
        document.write(quotes[i] + "\"");
        document.write("<em>-" + sources[i] + "</em>");
        document.write("</p>");
      }
      // Stop hiding the script -->
      </script>
      <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
    <body>
      <h1>Quotable Quotes</h1>
      <p>Followinhg is a randon quotable quote. To see a new quote just reload this page</p>

      <script>
        <!-- Hide the script from old browsers
        getQuote();
        // Stop hiding the script -->
      </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Math.random()** produces a random number between 0 and 1. And **quotes.length** wll return the number of items in the quotes array, which in your case is 4.

In the code, you are trying to get a random quote from the *quotes* array. And you must be knowing by now that to access an element from an array we have to use index.

So by this line, we are generating a valid random index that could help us get a quote out from the *quotes* array.

If you think, maximum length of *quotes* array could be 4 multiplied by (take the biggest random number Math.random() could generate) 0.9 which would be less than 4 and a float, so **Math.floor** takes care of that and rounds the number downwards to the nearest integer making it equal to 3 which is the last quote. And in this way you get random quotes.

`i = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);`

Now onto this:

It's just writing html to the DOM (Document Object Model). DOM defines the logical structure of the documents and the way in which they are accessed and manipulated.

So basically you are just writing the html encapsulated in the quotes to the document.

```
   document.write("<p style='background-color: #ffb6c1'>\");
   document.write(quotes[i] + "\"");
   document.write("<em>-" + sources[i] + "</em>");
   document.write("</p>");"
```

Comment: Thanks, Awesome great explanation. To take the example further why would do I get an "undefined" value whenever I use the math.ceil function instead? Is it because it is now rounding the number to four which in this case does not exist?

Comment: Yes @tony_ysl absolutely. Let's say if you got **0.9** as a random number and you multiply it with 4 (length of your **quotes** array), you'd get 3.6 and after using ceil it would take it to 4 which doesn't exist in the that array. Please consider marking it the correct answer if you found it useful :)

Comment: Hi @Tushar I have marked your answer useful, but I am getting this "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." everytime I click the up arrow.... your answer was great though, thank you :)